# Upload an image to DigitalOcean Spaces Object Storage from flutter not working for a real device

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I have managed to get the following piece of code working to upload images to digitalocean spaces  using same methods as s3 as guided [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/blob/main/packages/aws_signature_v4/example/bin/example.dart).

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:aws_common/aws_common.dart';
import 'package:aws_signature_v4/aws_signature_v4.dart';
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';
Future<String> imageUpload(File xfile, String uid) async {
  const awsAccessKeyId = 'xxxxxx';
  const awsSecretAccessKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  const region = 'blr1';
  const host = 'bucketname.$region.digitaloceanspaces.com';
  const folder = 'business_assets';
  final mimeType = lookupMimeType(xfile.path) ?? 'application/octet-stream';
  final ext = xfile.path.split('.').lastOrNull;
  final fileExt = ext != null ? '.$ext' : '';
  final filename = '${uid}_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}$fileExt';
  final path = '$folder/$filename';

  final serviceConfiguration = S3ServiceConfiguration();
  const awsCredentials = AWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey);
  const signer = AWSSigV4Signer(
    credentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials),
  );
  final scope = AWSCredentialScope(region: region, service: AWSService.s3);

  final file = File(xfile.path).openRead();
  final uploadRequest = AWSStreamedHttpRequest.put(
    Uri.https(host, path),
    body: file,
    headers: {
      AWSHeaders.host: host,
      AWSHeaders.contentType: mimeType,
      'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
    },
  );

  final signedUploadRequest = await signer.sign(
    uploadRequest,
    credentialScope: scope,
    serviceConfiguration: serviceConfiguration,
  );
  final headers = signedUploadRequest.headers;
  final uri = signedUploadRequest.uri;
  final uploadResponse = await signedUploadRequest.send().response;
  final uploadStatus = uploadResponse.statusCode;
  final resCodes = await uploadResponse.bodyBytes;
  final resdata = utf8.decode(resCodes);
  if (uploadStatus != 200) {
    throw Exception('Could not upload file');
  }
  return 'https://$host/$path';
}
```

But it works well in the simulator , but fails to work when i run the app in a real device .
I get the following error on a real device

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message></Message><RequestId>tx0000000d23c29d18ee2fc-00655e7f39-20443a-blr1a</RequestId><HostId>20443a-blr1a-blr1-zg01</HostId>
</Error>
```